# How to add a decimal to a 5 digit number

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office

I get a column of numbers that looks exactly like this:

4320923

What I need to do is turn the number into this:

+43.20923

How do I do this in format cell? I've been messing around and it looks like custom is the way to do this, i just don't know how. Any help would be great

Thank you

Comment: You say you have a column of numbers.  Are they stored as numbers or text (are they aligned in the left or right of the cell)?  Do you need the result to be numeric (something treated as a numerical value that you can do arithmetic with or graph), or just a string of numbers like a phone number?  Do you want the result to actually have that value (e.g., 43.20923), or retain the original value and just be displayed with a format that appears like that?  These are all different use cases with different solutions and the question is ambiguous.

Comment: Agreed with fixer. Both solutions given by Rajesh and Gary's student are valid, but they both answer a different need (number vs text). More information would have been helpful.

Comment: You accepted one answer and said that the other answer worked.  The two approaches do completely different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Select the data range and apply this Cell format you get the number as* **+43.20923**.

**N.B** *Remember this Format is applicable to ONLY 7 DIGIT numbers.*

**Check the Screen Shot:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

With your value in **A1**, in another cell enter:

```
="+" & LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-5)&"."&RIGHT(A1,5)
```

[image]